# Data displaying incorrectly after exporting to CSV sqlite3 Python

Tags: python, excel, database, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to export data from a table to a csv file. However, two of the columns containing a sum() from a pandas dataframe are displaying incorrectly.
The code I'm using is:

```
df6 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tblIncome", conn)
    df7 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tblCategory", conn)
    if sure == "Y":
        total_mnthinc = df6["IncomeAmount"].sum()
        print(total_mnthinc)
        total_mnthbudget = df7["CategoryMonthlyBudget"].sum()
        print(total_mnthbudget)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO tblTotal (TotalMonthlyIncome, TotalMonthlyBudget, UserID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                  (total_mnthinc, total_mnthbudget, "1"))
        conn.commit()
        menu()
```

The data is displaying as: TotalMonthlyIncome : [image]

The code being used for exporting is:

```
elif tbl_input == "E":
        print("Exporting CSV data to root directory of the Expense Management System... \n")
        data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM tblTotal')
        with open('tblTotalData.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(['TotalID', 'TotalMonthlyIncome', 'TotalMonthlyBudget', 'UserID'])
            writer.writerows(data)
        menu()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: After adding the lines in the comment below, it now displays as: [image]

EDIT 2: I have fixed it by adding:

```
            total_mnthinc = int(df6["IncomeAmount"].sum())
            print(total_mnthinc)
            total_mnthbudget = int(df7["CategoryMonthlyBudget"].sum())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be converted from bytes to int.

```
int.from_bytes(df6["IncomeAmount"].sum(), byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

Comment: I've just gone to add your code to my project and it's still not displaying properly.. New error is in an edit in the answer

Comment: Hey, That is displaying properly they are just large numbers, so either you have a giant monthly budget, or it isn't converting properly look at the documentation for that function. FYI click on the cell and change the format to not get exponential numbers.